# Using CSS to Control Position of Facebook Like / Send Buttons

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to position a Facebook like button (which includes a "Send" button) using CSS.  Below is the code provided by Facebook along with the div tag classed "like" that I added.  Below that is the corresponding CSS.  The CSS I am applying does not work; it seems to be overwritten by styling inherent in Facebook's code.

How can I position a Facebook like button using CSS?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
<div class="like">

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.like { 
            position:absolute;
            width:310px;
            left:30px;
            top:278px;
            color: #004993;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 15px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-top: 2px;

}
```

Comment: Do you have a demo or link? I can't see a reason why this would not work.

Comment: @Wesley Murch - Because the button renders inside an iframe.

Comment: I think that the iframe would be positioned in the same position as the .like div, so it should work

Comment: @miguelSantirso - yeah bad reading :/

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Just wrap an outside div around it and it'll work like a charm.

```
<div style="float:left; margin:10px 10px 0 0;">
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="yada-yada"></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure, if this is still open but the only solution is, if you do it like this:

```
<div id="fb-root" class="like">
```

a second way is,

```
<div id="fb-root" style="position:absolute; width:310px; left:30px; top:278px; color: #004993; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; height: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 5px; padding-top: 2px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with these solutions not working until I realized that Facebook's "GET CODE" wizard for the LIKE button defaults to a width of 450 pixels. I didn't pay attention to that, because the button looked OK on my site. But I finally realized that the Facebook LIKE code was grabbing a 450-pixel wide space, whether the button's info needed it or not. That is why I could not get all the various buttons to stay on the same line. Once I changed the width to 80, I did something similar to what was suggested above and it worked like a charm.

Duh. Eat humble pie.

Comment: You need change the size and others properties of div which is the FB buttom. See [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6568600/719323)

Answer (score 0):

My goal: Facebook-Follow-Button should show up to the right of a text-Label (Facebook: "Button")

```
<div style="float:left; width:80px;">Facebook:</div> 
<!-- float left + 80px, depends on text length, functions also as margin to beneath button div  -->

<div style="display:inline; position:relative; top:-20; width:100px;">
<!--  div block embracing fb-root, display: inline not necessary with fb but with twitter-button; top:-20 adjusting horizonal pos. -->

<div id="fb-root"></div>
</div>

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-follow" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/YOURFBLINK" data-width="150" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="button" data-show-faces="true"></div>

<br style="clear:both;"> <!-- prevents following stuff from floating next to our FB-Button-->
```

... --> Other Buttons...

Hope that helps folks!

Answer (score 0):

One of the quick ways to fix the pre-existing padding of the button is by understanding the background layout

```
<div class="like">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}" data-width="100" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-share="false"></div>
</div>

<style>
    .like{
        /*use background-color to understand the layout*/
        background-color: yellow;

        /*using flex just saves time here*/
        display: flex;

        /*if you're tryna position to the right*/
        justify-content: flex-end;

        /*adjust this according to the background-color layout */
        margin-right: -10px;

    }
</style>
```